# Can a collection of weighted graphs form a semiring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, semiring

I have tried to construct a semiring of wighted graphs, i.e., all the members of the semiring are 3-tuple elements. But i am worried wether i am ok? Because some say that the collection of graphs cannot form even a set. Please suggest me if my idea would work or not? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think you shouldn't really worry about whether they form a set or not: what are the addition and multiplication operations on this collection of graphs? I think these will be a bigger problem.

Comment: @joppy thanks for ur concern. Addition operation is more like radiographic minimum but not exactly lexicogrphic and multiplication operation is more like unions but not exactly the one.

Comment: # lexicogrphic minimum  not radiographic minimum